# Doubt about a function.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Can I construct a function $C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R})$, that is constant in some bounded interval, and nonconstant outside of this interval? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $N=1, f(x)=0$ for $|x| \leq 1$ and $f(x)=(x-1)^{2}(x+1)^{2}$ for $|x| >1$.